# Laravel 5.4.36 is not working properly for Registering new user on AWS ECS container

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5.4, amazon-ecs, fpm

I have a custom `RegisterController` which uses `RegistersUsers` trait for registering the users.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
       use RegistersUsers;
 ...
}
```

And in the web.php (where the routes are defined), I do the following to register the routes:
`Route::auth();`

On the View or frontend side, I have a customized the view (register.blade.php), where I am adding additional fields to the Register user form like below:
[image]

And on my RegisterController, I have following method to validate the form

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'gitHubUserName' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'gitHubToken' => 'required|string|min:1',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE that my users table do not store the GitHub User Name and GitHub Token.**

I have a `create` function on my `RegisterController` which takes care of managing (`inserting`) data into appropriate tables when validation passes (`users` is just a normal users table given by Laravel default users migration and I have another table that store the github userName and GitHubPwd).

If I do `php artisan --version`, I have `Laravel Framework 5.4.36` installed. Also I have `PHP 7.1.9` installed.

**Now this is working absolutely fine on my local MAMP development environment.**

The moment I push this on AWS ECS container and click Register button on my User Registration form, I am seeing some weird errors ... so this is not working.

Following are the errors:

**Error 1: PDOException:**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gitHubUserName' in 'where clause'
```

**Error 2:**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gitHubUserName' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `gitHubUserName` = tony)
```

So in short, what I noticed is that, **instead of calling my own validator for form request validation, the laravel provided `RegisterUser` trait class is calling the Model validator** as below :

[image]

So I referred to the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators) and also tried other approach by adding manual validator as explained in the documentation:

```
 $validator =  Validator::make(request(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'gitHubUserName' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'gitHubToken' => 'required|string|min:1',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

         if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
         }
```

I also did `composer dump-autoload, php artisan config:clear, php artisan cache:clear` after making the above change to code.

So now I am seeing different error:

[image]

And here is the partial (top most lines) of the call stack:

```
in Controller.php (line 82)

at Controller->__call('validator', array(array('_token' => 'S0c2YolcTS4AzvxIaehe6OMZ0E4LZKnFTd55nmio', 'name' => 'Tony', 'email' => 'tony@example.com', 'password' => 'Secret', 'password_confirmation' => 'Secret', 'gitHubUserName' => 'attres', 'gitHubToken' => '4365463463546354635465')))
in RegistersUsers.php (line 31)
at RegisterController->register(object(Request))
```

And again, everything works just fine on my local docker container or on MAMP development environment. When I build the new image, container and run it on AWS ECS container, I am seeing this issue. **Anyone has any clue regarding what may be the reason for this weird behaviour?**

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problem. I can't believe that I overlooked the validation rule syntax while trying to figure out the cause.

The problem lies in this validation rule within `Validator::make()` method:

> 'gitHubUserName' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',

There should not be `unique:users` because there is no gitHubUserName column in users table.

I changed the rule as below and everything started working fine again :

> 'gitHubUserName' => 'required|string|max:255'